# Web2py uploading big files ssl fails

Tags: java, memory, web2py

i hope get some help with this post.

I built a java console app that sends file to my web2py server.
This procedure just works to small files, when i try to send big file with 300Mb, i got a ssl fail.

In java side I have this code below to define my request:

```
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    httpConn.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
    httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
            true);
```

The exception returned in my java console application:

> java.io.IOException: Error writing request body to server

And this in my server side:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad RequestContent-Length: 11Content-Type: text/plainBad Request

If I comment this line: "httpConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);", i don't get this output anymore... But I got a Java heap space out of memory.

I have no idea how to solve that. I have searched in google but i got nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The peer has closed the connection but you are still sending. Probably you have exceeded some upload size limit.

Comment: How can i find out it?